# Passing Array count to a variable

Tags: php, arrays, count

I think I'm close with my code but I am trying to get the `count()` from the array provided... total users and OS

```
        $users = array();
        if ($results = $dbh->runQuery($sql)) {

foreach ($results as $key=>$row){
        $users[$row['user_id']][] = array('user_id'=>$row['user_id'],
        'email' => $row['email'],
        'last_login' => $row['last_login'],
        'fname' => $row['fname'],
        'lname' => $row['lname'], 
        'role_id' => $row['role_id'],
        'role_name' => $row['role_name'],
        'os_d_token' => $row['os'],
        'roid_d_token' => $row['roid'],
        'p_name' => $row['p_name']);
            }
        }
```

**Get total count of users**

```
    $user_cnt = count($row['user_id']);
```

**Get total count of users with OS**

```
    $total_os = '';
    if($row['os'] != null || '-1') {

        $total_os = count($row['os']);

    }
```

Comment: why not just count the `$results` array?

Comment: `$row['os']` is not an array.. maybe use a `COUNT` *in the SQL query*?

Comment: or use a incrementing counter

Comment: If you are making unique user entries with `$users[$row['user_id']][]`... then you may be wanting `count($users)` to find the end result of unique users?

Comment: @IncredibleHat So I can do $user_cnt = count($users); and get a count of the total users?

Comment: @acctman after you are done with the `foreach`, you can do that, and it should give you the count of users by unique user_id (as you have it). However getting count of unique OS would require a bit more like MattS's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` does not retain a counter for you.  It immediately returns the number of items in an array.  Since you're already looping, set counter variables:

```
$total = 0;
$total_os = 0;
foreach ($results as $key=>$row) {
    $total++;
    if ($row['os'] != null || $row['os'] != '-1') {
        $total_os++;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would add the $total++; code within the current foreach statement that I have running correct?